# PHP fullwidth latin characters to MySQL turns to weird things

Tags: php, mysql

first of all - this is not a duplicate. I searched for any solutions, but found none.

I try to save a text from php to mysql, which looks like this:
ＮＥＴＷＯＲＫ

But in MySQL, it will look like this:
ï¼®ï¼¥ï¼´ï¼·ï¼¯ï¼²ï¼«

I already tried different charsets:
big5, utf8 (not very intelligent), ujis, sjis, gb2312

If I print the text in PHP, it'll look right, so the problem is in MySQL.
Any ideas for what charset I can use?

Comment: I think your problem cause by your mysql client doesn't support that charset, the string wasn't common characters. I think it is not problem, it might be problem if you print wrong text in your browser.

Comment: You already admit the problem: you don't know what encoding your data is using. How PHP prints code is of little help because PHP strings are not encoding aware. If it's a new project just use UTF-8 everywhere. If it's legacy code/data you'll have to print hexadecimal values and figure out the encoding by yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: did you set your db connection to unicode, ie `SET NAMES utf8`?